# If many check boxes toggle event

Tags: javascript

I want to add toggle event to checkbox of some list items like

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Apple">
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Banana">
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Cucumber">
```

Javascript

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('list');

for(a=0; a<list.length; a++){

list[a].addEventListener('click',function(){

if ( list[a].checked ){ alert('Checked'); } else { alert('Unchecked'); }

}, false); 

}
```

nothing happens when i checked.

Comment: Do you run your Javascript after `document.ready` has fired?

Comment: this is not direcly the response you need, but don't use 'click' event, if people, like me, use often the keyboard to navigate you'll never trigger the 'clicked' event. consider the 'change' event instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this`, not `list[a].checked` in your loop:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('list');
for (a = 0; a < list.length; a++) {
    list[a].addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            console.log('Checked');
        } else {
            console.log('Unchecked');
        }
    }, false);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Apple">
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Banana">
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Cucumber">
```

`list[a]` would be equivalent to `list[3]` when the code runs, and there is no fourth list item.

Answer (score 0):

By the time your handlers actually run, `a == list.length`, so `list[a]` is undefined (as your JS console would have complained).

Instead, reference `this` to get the actual clicked element:

```js
function alertChecked() {
  if (this.checked) {
    alert('Checked');
  } else {
    alert('Unchecked');
  }
}

var list = document.getElementsByClassName('list');

for (a = 0; a < list.length; a++) {

  list[a].addEventListener('click', alertChecked, false);

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Apple">
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Banana">
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Cucumber">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it... more readable in my opinion :-)

I used 'change' event instead for better compatibility (keyboard navigation). 
And I prefer use a forEach loop :-)

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('list');

var alertOnChange = function(event) {
  alert( event.srcElement.checked ? "checked!" : "unchecked!")
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('change', alertOnChange);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Apple">
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Banana">
<input type="checkbox" class="list" value="Cucumber">
```